# Date default time zone wrong time

Tags: php, class, datetime, time

Im trying to figure out why i'm getting the wrong time, this is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam"); //Use the time of amsterdam
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("+".$tijd." minutes"); //Add the time in minutes to current time.
$datum = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

So when $tijd is set to 10, $datum returns this: 2015-02-28 14:49:00
But in Amsterdam the time is 14:10 at the moment (around that). So it should give something like 2015-02-28 14:20:00.

So what am i doing wrong since this is kinda weird, 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is my full-code:
  public function jail($tijd, $id){

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam"); //Use the time of amsterdam
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("+".$tijd." minutes"); //Add the time in minutes to current time.
$datum = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$conn = $this->conn;

$jail = $conn->prepare('UPDATE gebruikers
                          SET jail = :jail
                          WHERE id = :id');

$uitvoeren = $jail->execute(array(
    ':jail'  => $datum, 
    ':id'  => $id));

if($uitvoeren){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

And then in another PHP file:

```
$user = new user;

$tijd = 10;
$id = 1;

$gevangenis = $user->jail($tijd, $id);

if($gevangenis){
    echo 'Gelukt!';
} else {
    echo 'Mislukt!';
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me! Output right now: `2015-02-28 14:22:31` Is this your full and real code?

Comment: @Rizier123 No it isnt my full code. Im editting my post with the full code atm.

Comment: @Rizier123 Done the edit

Comment: And what output do you get now and what would you expect?

Comment: Check if the server time is correct

Comment: @Rizier123 How do i check servertime? And when i run the script at 14:38 i get this in the db: 2015-02-28 15:17:45

Comment: When you are on localhost just check the time on your computer

Comment: Im not on localhost. @Rizier123

Comment: @Rizier123 By the way, when i just submit the time without the modify im getting this: 2015-02-28 15:15:49 so there is like half an hour difference or something. But nothing to do with servertime since i set the default time mhh?

Comment: You can check the time of the server by reading the HTTP response. Just make any HTTP request and check the response header. You can use this command `curl -I http://address-of-server.com`

Comment: @user3160026 There it is! Your server time is 30 minutes in the future :D

Comment: @vanekjar I cant use that command, since i dont have a console or something, and i dont now where to find the HTTP response headers

Comment: @user3160026 You have to change the time of your server since your sever lives in the future :D

Comment: @Rizier123 But im not the owner of the server x'D. This is weird.

Comment: @Chiel Then you have to contact the server admin